# Ckeditor image upload working, but saying it doesn't (using ckfinder)

Tags: php, image, upload, ckeditor, ckfinder

I'm using ckeditor on my website (PHP,HTML,JavaScript), and I'd like my users to be able to upload image through the editor, but when I try to do it, the image appears like it's supposed to, then I get an error message in a pop-up saying the image couldn't be uploaded, when I click on the pop-up the image disappear.
The weird thing is that the image does get uploaded successfully in the right folder...

Anyone got any idea on how I could fix this ?

I don't really know what part of my code I should share, so feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was inside the script to create the editor:

```
ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
  ckfinder: {
        uploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images'
    },
```

it seems that ckfinder doesn't automatically return a response to let the editor know the file successfully uploaded, so i had to change it to this:

```
ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
  ckfinder: {
        uploadUrl: '/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images&responseType=json'
    },
```

My bad for not reading the docs correctly